# How do you login with your username instead of email?

Tags: feature-request, accounts

Or if that isn't possible, how can you find out what the email of an account is?

Comment: You can click the big bold **[contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)** link at the bottom of every page.

Comment: *clap clap clap*

Comment: @TinyGiant - I thought you meant that they'd have to contact Stack Exchange for help but nope, that really does show you your email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can click the big bold [**contact us**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page. – [Tiny Giant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant) [47 mins ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308130/how-do-you-login-with-your-username-instead-of-email?noredirect=1#comment258899_308130)

What I meant when posting that comment is that you could contact Stack Exchange for help. What I didn't realize when posting that comment is that the page at the other end of that link will auto-fill the contact form with your email address.

So, if you're logged in and you need to find out what email address is associated with your account you can click the big bold [**contact us**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page and it will show you your email address.

If you're not logged in and you need to find out what email address is associated with your account, you can still click on that big bold link at the bottom of every page to send an email to... someone that works at Stack Exchange. Make sure that your message clearly details the situation and that you give as much information as possible to identify yourself.

Comment: Alright.  The reason why I even asked this question was because I forgot the email address (or SE isn't recognizing the email address because I've tried all of them) of the account that I actually use.  I thought I used my main email address for it, but apparently not. When I cleared out my browser's cache, my logins were reset.  I forgot that I had this account which I never really used, so I'm trying to recover the main account.  I explained all of this in my message like you suggested.  Thank you.

Comment: Of course, if you're logged in and need to figure out the email associated with your account... Going to your logins on your profile (go to your profile > "Edit Profile & Settings"/"Settings" > "My Logins") works just as well. And you can even add an extra one there should you deem it necessary. (cc @daChi)